# Comparing Objects Directly to nil

Tags: objective-c, object, nullable, null

I have seen many posts here on Stack Overflow warning Objective-C users **not** to compare objects with the `==` operator. For example, the following is always recommended against.

```
if (string1 == string2) {} // string1 and string2 are both of type NSString *
```

I understand this warning as the `==` operator in this case checks for *pointer equality*, not the actual values of `string1` and `string2`. If this is the case, why do I so often see people comparing their objects to `nil` with the `==` operator. For example, I have seen the following several times.

```
if (obj == nil) {} // obj is of type id, or any other object
```

If comparing pointers with the `==` operator is bad practice on things like `NSString`s (or `NSNumber`s or `NSArray`s etc), then why is it so commonplace with `nil`.

Is this the standard because there is only one type of `nil` i.e.: `nil` always equals `nil`? 
**Why are direct comaprisons using the `==` operator frowned upon between objects, but let slip when comparing to `nil`?**

Thank your for your time.

Comment: It's not that you _shouldn't_ compare pointers, it's that people frequently don't realize that it's not doing content comparison. You certainly can use `==` if you really need to test object identity: `if( objectIJustGotOutOfDataStructure == objectIAlreadyHave ){ //...`

Comment: @JoshCaswell Great Point, I agree that most people just use `==` when they are trying to (erroneously) compare the values in the strings, and do not realize that they are performing a pointer equality test.

Comment: That's what I'm saying; the warning is just about that, not about using `==` in general.

Comment: Both kinds of equality checking have there uses and understanding the difference is better than generalizing and saying you should always do it a certain way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using == tests for pointer equality, which seems to be what you want to test for in this particular case. You are checking whether some pointer is a nil pointer. Specifically, a pointer that equals zero. Comparing objects is more complicated as you've pointed out. Equality between objects often relies on some internal part of the two objects being "the same".

In the case of strings, "equality" can mean "has the same characters" but it could also mean "has the same characters (ignoring capitalization)". There are also cases where you might want a nil string to equal an empty string or even a string with just whitespace. The point is that you must understand the different methods of determining equality in order to implement your own definition of equality for your objects.

Note that checking for pointer equality is almost never what you want to use when comparing things like strings or arrays. There are some interesting optimizations that can throw you off. For example, all empty NSArray's point to the same singleton object.

Answer (score 1):

`nil` is like `NULL` from C or `std::nullptr` in C++. Basically points to nothing.

When a object in Objective-C is unallocated (haven't been alloc), the pointer **will** be `nil`.

So `if (obj == nil)` will check if `obj` is allocated (or initialized as they often happen together)

This technique is often used when writing a custom initializer or checking if some object exists or not.

Comment: Detail: a local, uninitialized object pointer will be `nil` only if you are compiling with ARC. Otherwise it's undefined, like any other variable.

Comment: Everything is so much simpler with ARC!